# Nodejs Sequelize Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

My goal is to find id in JSONB.
I am using DataTypes.JSONB.

My data looks like:

```
{"id": ["8a20b9c0-d3c5-11ea-895e-8757d6b9cab5", "8a1f3320-d3c5-11ea-895e-8757d6b9cab5", "8a226770-d3c5-11ea-895e-8757d6b9cab5"]}
```

Query I am using and NOT working:

```
Product.findAll({
            where:{  
              'sub_category_ids.id': {
                [Op.contains]: '["'+req.params.subcategoryId+'"]'
              }
```

Raw query look like and NOT working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Products" AS "Product" 
WHERE ("Product"."sub_category_ids"#>>'{id}') @> '["8a1f3320-d3c5-11ea-895e-8757d6b9cab5"]' 
ORDER BY "Product"."createdAt" DESC;
```

I am not getting any result. But when I use this query, it is working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Products" AS "Product" 
WHERE ("Product"."sub_category_ids"->'id') @> '["8a20b9c0-d3c5-11ea-895e-8757d6b9cab5"]';
```

What I am doing wrong Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Product.findAll({
        where:{  
          sub_category_ids: {
            id:{
             [Op.contains]: '["'+req.params.subcategoryId+'"]'
            } 
          }
         }
       })
```

Comment: No luck, getting the same result:
SELECT * FROM "Products" AS "Product" WHERE ("Product"."sub_category_ids"#>>'{id}') @> '["e5e26820-d3d0-11ea-90d4-897cfb2a628a"]' ORDER BY "Product"."createdAt" DESC;